# Proving Limit By Definition

Tags: calculus

> Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{2x+1}{3x-1}=\dfrac{3}{2}$

So I need to find $\delta$ that if $|x-1|<\delta$ so $|\frac{2x+1}{3x-1}-\frac{3}{2}|<\epsilon$

I manage to get to this point:

$$\left|\frac{2x+1}{3x-1}-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{-5x+5}{2(3x-1)}\right|=\frac{5|-x+1|}{2|3x-1|}=\frac{5|x-1|}{2|3x-1|}$$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take a neighborhood of $1$. For exemple $I=[\frac{1}{2},2]$. Therefore $\frac{1}{|3x-1|} \leq 2$ if $x\in I$. Take $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{5}$ and conclude.

Comment: why does $\frac{1}{|3x-1|}\leq 2$ ?

Comment: ??? On $I$, $|3x-1|=3x-1$. Moreover, $x\geq \frac{1}{2}\implies 3x\geq \frac{3}{2}\implies 3x-1\geq \frac{3}{2}-1=\frac{1}{2}\implies \frac{1}{|3x-1|}\leq 2$.